# Git: Update repository without losing commits

Tags: git, pull

I'm a novice in git. I'm working on on project X.
I have the following problem:

**Remote**

Origin -> A - B - C

BranchX -> A - B - D

**Local**

Origin -> A - B

BranchX -> A - B - D

How do I get commit C to BranchX in my local such that the local repo looks like this:

**Local**

Origin -> A - B - C

BranchX -> A - B - C - D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you make sure you have `BranchX` checked out

```
git checkout BranchX
```

then update your local `Origin` branch from remote

```
git fetch origin Origin:Origin
```

lastly rebase your `BranchX` onto the `Origin` branch

```
git rebase Origin
```